# What's the best way to have multiple groups of simple featured products in Magento?

Tags: magento

I would like to have a small number of pages on my site that have some text, and then an associated group of products eg, here is a picture of a nice kitchen, the things we sell that are included in this picture are below. I would like people to be able to click on the product and be taken to that product's page AND I plan to implement functionality that would allow you to add all of the products directly to the basket.

Caveat: All of my main product pages are of Configurable Products, and I would like to "Feature" certain Simple Products on the above pages, eg: this is a picture of a kitchen, we are using a blue lamp. This links directly to the "Lamp" page, but if you add this to basket, you'll get a blue lamp.

I have created the pages as Magento CMS pages and had created a specific inactive category of products for each page. This doesn't work because it links directly to the product in the inactive category, and not the actual category, eg: clicking wants to take you to /kitchinA/lampA.html instead of /lamps/lampA.html

What is the best way for me to include multiple groups of "featured" products, on different pages?

Answer (score 0):

How about using related products?